# Unable to install xlwings package into Spyder

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, spyder, xlwings

I have program that uses xlwings. When I first wrote it, I was using Spyder inside of Anaconda. Now I downloaded Spyder separately and I have tried to use the anaconda command prompt in the Spyder environment to install but Spyder still doesn't have the module.

In the anaconda prompt I used the following line :

```
conda create -n my-env -c conda-forge spyder-kernels xlwings
```

Everything seem to have downloaded successfully, but after closing out of Spyder and re-opening it, I am still unable to use xlwings.

Comment: It sounds like you are happy to use `conda`, so it's not clear why you changed to a separately downloaded version of Spyder? Anyway, it sounds as if Spyder is using a Python interpreter in a different environment from the one into which you installed xlwings. If you do the commands `conda activate my-env` followed by `spyder` and check that 'Python interpreter' in Spyder's preferences is set to 'default' (assuming Spyder 5.x) then it should work.